# How do you update a users profile settings using firebase and swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, user-profile

I am trying to update a users email and full name. This is my code:

func saveTapped() {

```
    var performSegue = false

    if updateEmail.text == "" && updateFullName.text == "" {
        self.cleanUrCodeRohan("Please fill in one or more of the missing text fields that you would like to update.")
    }

    if updateEmail.text != "" {

        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

        user?.updateEmail(updateEmail.text!) { error in
            self.ref.child("users").child(self.currentUser).child("email").setValue(self.updateEmail.text!)

        }

        let emailUpdateRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(currentUser).child("email")
        print(emailUpdateRef)
        emailUpdateRef.setValue(self.updateEmail.text)

        performSegue = true
    }

    if updateFullName.text != "" {
        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        if let user = user {
            let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest.displayName = self.updateFullName.text!
        }
        performSegue = true
    }

    if performSegue == true {
        self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

I am able to update the email under authorization but not under the database. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "under authorization but not under the database"? Do you have database rules where you have users: { user: { email: "somethid@gmail.com"} }  ?

Comment: Inside user?.updateEmail(updateEmail.text!) { error in
            self.ref.child("users").child(self.currentUser).child("email").setValue(self.updateEmail.text!)

        } you may want to check for if (error != nil) { print("something wrong happened!!"}

Comment: no i mean under database not authorization

Comment: I already got the authorization part working

Comment: I have answered your question :)Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JSON tree is something like this:-

```
 appName{
     users :{
         userID :{
             email : "..",
             username : ".."
         }
     }
 }
```

Use this Code to update your node's child value's:-

```
func saveTapped(){

if ((updateEmail.text != "" || updateFullName.text != "") && (updateEmail.text != nil || updateFullName.text != nil)){

    let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)
    if let new_Email = updateEmail.text as? String{

        FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.updateEmail(updateEmail.text!) { error in

            if error == nil{
                userRef.updateChildValues(["email" : new_Email ], withCompletionBlock: {(errEM, referenceEM)   in

                    if errEM == nil{
                        print(referenceEM)
                    }else{
                        print(errEM?.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
            }
        }else{
            self.cleanUrCodeRohan("Email couldn't be updated in auth")
        }
    }

    if let new_Name = updateFullName.text as? String{

        userRef.updateChildValues(["username" : new_Name ], withCompletionBlock: {(errNM, referenceNM)   in

            if errNM == nil{
                print(referenceNM)
            }else{
                print(errNM?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }

}else{

    self.cleanUrCodeRohan("Please fill in one or more of the missing text fields that you would like to update.")

    }
}
```

Comment: I have one more question, how would I update a photo url saved in my database. It is the same son tree you showed above it just has another thing called photo url: "PHOTOS URL". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it does not let me do it i do not have enough reputation. sorry!

Comment: @RohanVasishth glad to help. Delete your previous comments and Accept all the previous answers which have helped you solve your issue in your previous query's, So that other users know wether the answer was helpful or not and which in general is just a nice thing to do :) Happy Coding